# Get mysql table name from query result

Tags: php, mysql

I want to display statistics about a mysql table using this Query:

```
select * from t1 where product = ABC
Union
select * from t2 where product = ABC
```

The above query produces 2 rows with product="ABC" in t1 and 3 rows with product="ABC" in t2.  The query doesn't tell me which table it came from.

How can the query be changed so I can know the source table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can include a unique token in each query to let you know which table the data came from like this:

```
select *, 't1' as tablename from t1 where product = 'ABC'
Union  
select *, 't2' as tablename from t2 where product = 'ABC'
```